# Limit Power Automate Flow Trigger to Specific Excel Table

Tags: power-automate

Is there a way to control a Power Automate Flow based on which table is updated in an Excel file?

I have one Flow that reads table data when the Excel file has been modified. I also have another Flow that will update a row, in this same file but a different table, when a SharePoint list is modified. The Flow that runs when the list is modified is kicking off the flow when the Excel file is modified, which I don't need or want.

Is there any way to qualify which table is being updated to allow/prevent the Flow to continue running? Is there something available in MS Graph maybe?

This is not preventing any work, it's more of an annoyance and the fact that it contributes to daily limits.

In Power Automate, I don't see any way to identify which table has been updated to allow/prevent the Flow from continuing.

Comment: Nah, from my experience, it's not possible.  Could you have that table in an isolated file and then sync them with a main file when it's updated?  Annoying as hell but it could help you.

Comment: @Skin I believe that would still activate the "modified" trigger, would it not? Not a bad idea though, if I can get away with linking the external table this would be a good option. thank!

Comment: You should be able to isolate the folder that the file is stored in so it doesn’t fire the trigger. Mind you, I don’t know which trigger you’re using because you haven’t specified that.

Comment: Thank you @Skin, moving the file to its own folder prevented trigger from being activated unnecessarily.

Comment: Maybe I’ll add that as an answer for you and you can flag it. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, **no**, it's not possible.

To overcome this, you could have that table in an isolated file and then sync them with a main file when it's updated.

Annoying as hell but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

The following work-around may help you only run some Power Automate actions when rows of a specific Excel table are created, modified, or deleted...

Workaround for "When an Excel row is created", "When an Excel row is modified", and/or "When an Excel row is deleted" triggers

This template triggers some time after users edit an Excel workbook in SharePoint & then for the target Excel table, returns a different set for records that were created, records that were modified, & records that were deleted. This way we can set up additional actions & processes for each edit users made in our target Excel table.
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Automate-Cookbook/When-an-Excel-row-is-created-modified-or-deleted-workaround/td-p/2264670